# office-js add-in in offline mode

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to develop a new office add-in. Can i send the `add-in` (or the manifest itself) to the end user, without a server? To clarify, the contents of `manifest.xml` are:

```
<DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
</DefaultSettings>
```

It is looking for the `taskpane` on localhost. If i change it to a server (`aws` for examle), it works.

Could use the add-in without a server, so it works offline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but an Office Web Add-in cannot run offline currently. There has to be a server to host the HTML and JavaScript. We're working on supporting offline operation of add-ins, but we don't know when that will be available.

Comment: does it must be a "running server" like azure? or a public location like amzon S3?

Comment: @ben.spectory The add-in is like a static website, so you could host it from an S3 bucket.

Comment: @Lumpenstein is correct. You can host an add-in in any of the ways that any other web application can be hosted. See [Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins).

Comment: One more question: do you know why the same add in with custom function (which includes fetch function to another api) woks on office 365 on the web but does not work on office on windows (the office was downloaded from office 365 account and connected to my office 365 account) the only problem is with the fetch function.